# Strange template template parameter expected error

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-templates

When trying to compile this piece of code :

```
template <class URNG>
struct Dumb : Brain<Dumb, URNG>
{
    Move operator()(const Rat<Dumb, URNG>& rat, URNG&& urng)
    {
        Move move;
        move.x = 1;
        move.y = 0;
        //rat.look(1, 2);
        //rat.getDna(35);
        return move;
    }
};
```

clang 3.2.7 raise, this strange error I don't understand :

```
main.cpp:10:28: error: template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template
        Move operator()(const Rat<Dumb, URNG>& rat, URNG&& urng)
                                  ^
```

Dumb is a class template isn't it ?

As asked in the comments, here is what rat looks like :

```
template <template <class> class BRAIN, class URNG>
class Rat
{
//...
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `Rat`?

Comment: I just added what rat template looked like.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  I think you might be right... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is because of injected names:

```
template <class URNG>
struct Dumb : Brain<Dumb, URNG>
{
    // in here, "Dumb" refers to the complete type "Dumb<URNG>"
    Move operator()(const Rat<Dumb, URNG>& rat, URNG&& urng)
                          //  ^^^^ 
                          //  really a type, not a template
```

To fix that, you need to reference the uninjected name, which you can do thusly:

```
template <class URNG>
struct Dumb : Brain<Dumb, URNG>
{
    Move operator()(const Rat<::Dumb, URNG>& rat, URNG&& urng)
                          //  ^^^^^^
                          //  actual Dumb<T> template, not type
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks ! I hadn't thought about this problem of referencing the type or the template inside the struct.

Comment: This is a compiler bug. The injected class name should be treated as a template when used as an argument for a template template parameter.

Comment: @T.C. Ah, didn't realize that changed in C++11. But for C++03, it'd be correct to reject it - and it's unclear if OP is using C++11 or not.

Comment: @Barry `URNG&&`, hint, hint. (And for C++03, you'd need a space before `::Dumb` ;) )